# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Users

Tags: ubuntu, users

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I'm a root user and wanted to create another user, who mainly access through FTP and needs to have permission to write, delete and add files.

What's the best and most secure way to do this? I'm reading, but can't find and easy answer.

EDIT: Let me add a few more things.

I already have a folder where I have my websites and other things, this folder is owned by my user ( root ). I want this new user to edit, add and delete files from this folder too.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the user in the usual way (e.g., using `useradd` from the command line, or use whatever GUI control you're comfortable with).

If you need to give him access to existing folders, one way is to create a new group for such users (e.g., "ftpuser") and set the permissions on the target folder(s) appropriately:

```
useradd -m -c "Real Name" -G ftpuser loginname && passwd loginname
chgrp ftpuser targetfolder && chmod g+rwx targetfolder
```

Use chmod and chgrp to give him access to other folders as needed.

Comment: Thank you! I've already did it, but the problem is I have a folder which the group owner is the root and I can't do anything there with this new user.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: change the group to something else (maybe make a new group called "ftpusers") and make the new user part of that group.

Comment: Thanks. I've done it, but I still have some problems. Let me try to be precise.

I created group www-users and added my user dani to this group. 
Used the command chgrp to change the folder global group to www-users.

Everything looks great but, if User root creates a folder, dani can't add/remove/create files or more folders inside it.

Does it mean it's because when user root creates it, the group isn't set as www-users? 

Any tip how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: That's right. And you don't want to have every file root creates to be in the www-users group. So you probably want a different user instead of root who's default group is also www-users to make those files.

Comment: I haven't thought about it, I guess I'm changing it and having a different user for myself.

Any idea how can I have an user that belongs to www-users, when these create a file or directory, the default group is www-users and not themselves?

I was checking setfacl, but it didn't worked out. :/

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Well, I did this:

`sudo chgrp -R www-users global/ .`

And then:

`chmod g+s .`

At the main folder, global. But, when creating a directory or file inside it, it still sets the group as dani .

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `usermod -g www-users myusername` to change the default group for myusername.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I thinks it's the only thing missing. If user1 creates a file and user2 edits, it has no permission. The file is being created with 644 permissions, making the group not allowed to write. Any idea how I can change the default permissions for these users? I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Use `umask 002` in that user's environment

Answer (score 0):

Set all directories at or under the global folder to be set-gid.

```
find global -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs "{}" +
```

To correct any straggler files/directories, set them all correctly at that point.

```
find global -exec chgrp www-users "{}" +
```

After that any files created *in that directory structure* will be in the www-users group.